# ∅ Three Potholes

Tags: articles, numbers

> **Three potholes** in the road were completely filled by the city to avoid further traffic accidents. (Grammar Book)

According to the rule of "the," this being without it, it means that there are more than three.

But it is strange to think that.

So is this rule that says, "If the number represents the total, then it's 'the'. If the number is only part of the whole, then no 'the'." just a rule of thumb?

But is it possible, if we disregard the unnaturalness, to think that there are more than three potholes on the road, hence no definite article?

Comment: While describing such work (by municipality or body the like) I don't think the definite article is required. *Municipality workers repaired 5 street lights last night.* I'd be least bothered which lights. If you put *the*, it'd be very specific. The sentence could be - *Municipality workers repaired the 5 street lights at Times Square last night.* It'd also mean there are **only** 5 street lights and they were repaired.

Comment: but "in the road" is added...so it becomes more complicated. But would you agree with my comment below? @Maulik V

Answer (score 1):

> **Three potholes** in the road were completely filled by the city to avoid further traffic accidents.

This indeed leaves an impression that there may exist other potholes on that road. But it's not so simple with **the**.

> **The three potholes** in the road were completely filled by the city to avoid further traffic accidents.

If the writer was speaking of the road in preceding sentences, but did not mention potholes on this road at all, this sentence would mean that there're indeed only three:

> A short span of road has been reopened today after maintenance. **The three potholes** in the road were completely filled by the city to avoid further traffic accidents.

But if he has already mentioned these 3 particular potholes, the definite article would not mean there's only 3:

> A short span of road has been reopened today after maintenance, with **3 roundish spots** of fresh asphalt visible on the surface. **The three potholes** in the road were completely filled by the city to avoid further traffic accidents.

The latter passage says nothing of the total number of potholes on the road, but allows for the existence of others. We may well find the next sentence saying that

> The locals were quick to notice several other, less prominent potholes still unfilled.

Concerning your question:

> So is this rule that says, "If the number represents the total, then it's 'the'. If the number is only part of the whole, then no 'the'." just a rule of thumb?

If I understood you correctly, I'd put it thus. If we have

1. A mention of a group of countable items (potholes, lampposts, etc.), with a numeral adjective (3 or 5 or 6 etc.);
2. This group of items is part of some larger but finite entity or area (they are in a road, or in a park, or part of a factory), and this is made clear in the text;
3. This group of items is mentioned for the first time;
4. And this group of items takes **THE**,

then the mentioned number is the total number of such items belonging to this particular entity or area.

Comment: I'd say "three potholes " means either just three or more than three. just like in "I picked up a book on the table" in this case, it could be either "only one book" or "one among many on the table."

Comment: Everything pretty much depends on the context.

Comment: You're probably right, I've edited my answer. "**A** book" leaves open the possibility that there are other books on the table. But it probably also allows that the picked book was the only one there.

Comment: That's right! What I wanted to highlight here is the ambivalence this case adds to the commonplace explanation of the definite article.

Comment: Yes, simple explanation do not cover all aspects of article usage.

Comment: I'm afraid I won't be able to do it. In "A comprehensive grammar of the English language" (Quirk et al, 1985) there are roughly **30 pages** dedicated to articles.